# Run same query in SSMS on multiple databases in the same server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

It is possible in SSMS to run the same query on some databases?
I was thinking something like an array with database names and cycling through it, maybe with SQLCMD mode.

some pseudocode:

```
:setvar arr ["db1", "db2", "db3"]
foreach $db in $arr
    :setvar database $db
    use $(database)
    go
    select * from table
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use the (undocumented) `sp_MSForeachdb`, see [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx)

Comment: Are these databases on the same instance? Then you can use the sp foreach database. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx. Note: this guy is undocumented

Comment: Ok, this will work, but i need to apply only to some databases in the instance, not all.

Comment: Is it the exact same table in all the databases or are you wanting to iterate through multiple tables in each database as well?

Comment: the table is exactly the same, only the db changes

Answer (score 2):

```
--  To Achive your Desire OutpUt You Have to Use Dynamic Query
-- you can Achieve this in TSQL 
-- TO Know The Database ID  Run Below Query
/*
SELECT * FROM Sys.databases WHERE database_id >4
*/



 USE MASTER
    GO
    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @strt INT,@End INT,@Database NVARCHAR(255)

    SELECT * INTO #T FROM Sys.databases WHERE database_id IN (4,5,6)-- Here you Have to Defined the Database ID 
    ORDER BY 1

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()OVER (ORDER BY database_Id)Db_Id,* INTO #TT FROM #T
    SET @strt=1
    SELECT @End=Max(Db_ID)FROM #tt

    WHILE @strt<=@END
         BEGIN
             DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)
             SELECT @Database=NAME FROM #TT WHERE Db_ID=@strt

            Set @string='  Select * from '+@Database+'..Table_Name'

              SET @strt=@strt+1
              PRINT @string
              EXEC(@string)
         END

    ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: this will select all dbs in the instance; i need only some db defined by me.

Comment: @ʞᴉɯ I Had Edited The ans you can check Now

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Local Server Group as well.

- View --> Registered Servers
- Right-click Local Server Group and create new
- Add new server registrations to the group (any databases you want to query). Be sure to specify the database in the Connection Properties tab

Now you can right-click the Local Server Group folder and execute a new query, which will run on all the databases in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using two of my databases (Staging and Warehouse) to hit the sys.columns table in each. Just change out the IN filter with the names of whichever databases you want, and the ".sys.columns" with the schema/table name you need.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
;

SELECT @query += CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',[name],'.sys.columns;')
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] IN ('Staging','Warehouse')
;

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```